# How to convert from mouse coordinates to world coordinates in a Javascript canvas game?

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas, transform

I'm developing a simple top-down game in Javascript using the 2d Canvas API. At the moment, I have the camera always centered on the player, such that they are always in the center of the screen. This is done like this:

```
let camX = -player.pos.x + this.canvas.width / 2;
tet camY = -player.pos.y + this.canvas.height / 2;

this.context.translate(camX, camY);
```

And it seems to work just fine. My issue comes in when I want to have the player click somewhere on the screen and have that click be translated into world coordinates. That is, if the player clicks somewhere, I should be able to use the relative mouse position combined with the camera transformation to obtain the world coordinates of the click.

I thought it would as simple as the following:

```
let worldX = -camX + input.mousePosition.x;
let worldY = -camY + input.mousePosition.y;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. If I was using a normal camera object I would just take the inverse matrix I think, but this is just a simple canvas, so I'm not sure if I can do that in this case.

Comment: Why use translate? sounds like it will be easier to draw the player at the center of the canvas

Comment: Because the player moves about the world and has world coordinates. The camera is the canvas which is translated to pan to keep the player in the center of the screen.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see a need to use translate, you can draw the player at the center of the canvas without using translate ... maybe you can put a minimal working code snippet together showing the problem

Comment: It's not just the character. _Everything_ is translated. It's a large world with a small camera.

Comment: When you say it doesn't seem to be working, what is the problem? Do you get garbage values, wrong values etc?

Comment: The position is just off. That is, in game I'm marking on the world where it's being set, and the value is not correct. It's a decent-sized distance away from where it should be.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I realized the issue. It's because I am scaling the canvas. So I just need to account for that scale factor somehow into the calculation.

Comment: ... I get a feeling you are not using a game engine, what you describe in the comments: large world, translation, scaling and user input is something that has been solved ... there are a lot of free and open source engines just pick one and save yourself some headaches: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Comment: The game is almost done at this point. I'm fine not using an engine.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/xsz8etbq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It's because I was using zoom, which was throwing off the calculation. I'm not sure how to do it manually, but I found out that the canvas has matrix transform and inverse functions, so I created these two functions, which seem to work:

```
static getWorldCoordsFromRelative(ctx: any, position: Vec2) {
  let matrix = ctx.getTransform();
  var imatrix = matrix.invertSelf();

  return new Vec2(position.x * imatrix.a + position.y * imatrix.c + imatrix.e,
                  position.x * imatrix.b + position.y * imatrix.d + imatrix.f);
}

static getRelativeCoordsFromWorldCoords(ctx: any, position: Vec2) {
  let matrix = ctx.getTransform();
  
  return new Vec2(position.x * matrix.a + position.y * matrix.c + matrix.e,
                  position.x * matrix.b + position.y * matrix.d + matrix.f);
}
```